# C sprintf function that uses malloc or the stack

Tags: c, gcc, printf, alloca

I've heard there is a version of `sprintf()`, possibly a GNU/gcc extension which either allocates its own buffer which I must `free()` or perhaps works using the stack like `alloca()`.

Either method is fine for me. Can anyone tell me what function I was thinking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean [asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) ?

From the man page:

---

**Description**

*The functions asprintf() and vasprintf() are analogues of sprintf() and vsprintf(), except that they allocate a string large enough to hold the output including the terminating null byte, and return a pointer to it via the first parameter. This pointer should be passed to free(3) to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.*

---

Note that asprintf is a GNU extension, which is also found in various BSD implementations, but it's not in standard C or POSIX.

Comment: It doesn't matter too much that this function is nonstandard, because it can be implemented as a trivial wrapper around `vsnprintf` (standard C99) or `open_memstream` and `vfprintf` (POSIX 2008 and C89, respectively).